# Get email count of search results in Gmail API

Tags: gmail-api

I am implementing email functionality using PHP using Google API PHP SDK and I want to get total count of emails for search result.

I managed to get email count of inbox, sent mails, specific labels etc. but there is no option to count total number of emails in the search result.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Genext. Please post the code you have so far, along with sample details of the details you're able to retrieve. How are you *searching* for this specific *results*? Are you looking for an API that directly provides the details?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here is the code. 
    `//code for fetching inbox
    $inboxArr = array('labelIds'=>'INBOX','maxResults'=>$displayCount);
    $inboxArr['pageToken'] = $_REQUEST['token'];
    $inboxArr['q'] = 'in:inbox '.urlencode($_REQUEST['searchInput']) ;
    
    //getting results on the basis of parameters & search filters
    $results = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages($user,$inboxArr);

    //code for fetching mail count
    $labelsResponse = $service->users_labels->get($user,'INBOX');

    $totalMails = $labelsResponse->getThreadsTotal();`